# How can I set up own authorities in Spring Boot Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have defined my spring security like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
```

And my CustomUserDetail like this:

```
private User user;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    // Get user information
    String role = user.getRole();
    boolean write = user.isWrite();
    boolean read = user.isRead();

    // Set the authorities
    HashSet<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>(AUTHORITIES);
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toUpperCase())); 
    if(write == true)
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("WRITE")); 
    if(read == true)
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("READ")); 

    return authorities;
}
```

As you see, I give the auths "ROLE", "WRITE" and "READ".

How can I describe in Spring Security that I want only give some users e.g "USER" with the right "WRITE" to access just that page?

Spring Security have the method  `hasAuthority("USER")` and `hasAnyAuthority("USER")`. Can can't set `hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "WRITE")` because what if the USER acces an admin page if the USER have the auth "WRITE"?

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 3 Roles as *ADMIN*, *USER_RW*, *USER_R*

- *ADMIN*: will have all the authority
- *USER_RW*: the user who can perform read-write
- *USER_R*: the user who can only read

Granting user an authority with *WRITE*, *READ* and `hasAuthority("USER")`, `hasAuthority("ADMIN")` doesn't make sense as you are granting authority as *WRITE*, *READ* and checking for a role which you have never assigned to them. you may have something as follow.

```
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLENAME")); 
.antMatchers("/endpoint/**").hasAuthority("ROLENAME")
```

Comment: Ok. So ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER_RW and ROLE_USER_R is only avaiable?

Comment: This is just suggested role names, you can have multiple roles as per requirements. The issue is you are asking to spring boot to check role which you have never assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict an endpoint to a user that has authorities `"ROLE_USER"` **AND** `"READ"`, then you can use the [access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#access-java.lang.String-) method to specify an expression. You can chain attributes using the `and` keyword.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER') and hasAuthority('READ')");
```